# Can't login to Redmine after install, Internal error 500

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine, webrick

I have

- Debian GNU/Linux unstable (sid), Linux zoonman
  2.6.32-308.8.2.el5.028stab101.1 #1 SMP Sun Jun 24 20:25:35 MSD 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux
- mysql Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.32-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.1
- redmine-2.3.2
- ruby 1.9.3
- Rails 3.2.13

  ```
  # RAILS_ENV=production script/about

  Environment:
          Redmine version                2.3.2.stable
          Ruby version                   1.9.3-p194 (2012-04-20) [x86_64-linux]
          Rails version                  3.2.13
          Environment                    production
          Database adapter               Mysql2
  Redmine plugins:
          no plugin installed

  # ruby script/rails server webrick -e production

  => Booting WEBrick
  => Rails 3.2.13 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:3000
  => Call with -d to detach
  => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
  [2013-09-04 06:22:31] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
  [2013-09-04 06:22:31] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2012-04-20) [x86_64-linux]
  [2013-09-04 06:22:31] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=11329 port=3000

  [... skipped...]

  Started POST "/login" for 1.2.3.4 at 2013-09-04 06:22:52 +0400
  Processing by AccountController#login as HTML
          Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"qXvGycxPPcjjfS3cNpO/gDw2h+OXGYF3pGkUmzoRk3M=", "back_url"=>"http://zoonman.com:3000/", "username"=>"admin", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "login"=>"Login »"}
          Current user: anonymous
  Successful authentication for 'admin' from 1.2.3.4 at 2013-09-04 02:22:52 UTC
  Redirected to http://zoonman.com:3000/
  Completed 302 Found in 42ms (ActiveRecord: 6.7ms)

  NoMethodError (undefined method `options' for {:user_id=>1, :ctime=>1378261372, :atime=>1378261372}:Hash):
          /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:329:in `commit_session'
          /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:226:in `context'
          /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
          /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in `call'
          /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
          /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
          /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
          /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__413405940092677981__call__2271426155153417099__callbacks'
          /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
          /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
          /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
          /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
          /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
          /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
          /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
          /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
          /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
          /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
          /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
          /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
          /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
          /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
          /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
          /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
          /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:63:in `call'
          /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
          /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rack/cache/context.rb:143:in `pass'
          /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rack/cache/context.rb:155:in `invalidate'
          /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rack/cache/context.rb:71:in `call!'
          /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
          /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
          /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
          /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
          /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
          /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
          /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
          /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
          /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
  ```

I followed instructions on install page, but I can't login to admin account. I don't know anything about Ruby and ROR applications.
How to figure out, where is issue? And how fix it?

Comment: Try to look [here](https://github.com/backlogs/redmine_backlogs/issues/852) They have similar problem. I do see that you don't have installed plugins but the solution was to change version of rack. Try to update/downgrade the rack version - maybe it helps you. PS Our redmine (v2.3.2) uses rack (1.4.5)

Comment: I'm having the same error. @zoonman how did you generate this log?

Comment: I run webrick and it shows me details.